# I want to check whether the products exists in cart then show a added icon in webpage using django and jinja

Tags: python, html, django

I have a singleproduct page in which I have a add to cart button but if that product already exists in the cart I want to show a Added to cart icon instead.I am not able to figure out the way to check that.
Here is my **models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=False)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    productid=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And here is my **views.py**

```
def singleproduct(request, id):
context = {
    'types': Category.objects.all(),
    'prods': Product.objects.filter(productid = id),
    'in_cart': False,
}
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    order = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=request.user.customer, complete=False)[0]
    context['in_cart'] = order.products.filter(product_id=id).exists()
return render(request,"singleproduct.html", context)    

def cart(request):
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
        context={
            'items':items,
            'order':order
        }
        return render(request,"cart.html",context)


def category(request):
context = {
    'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    'prods': Product.objects.filter(),
    'cartItems':[],
    'in_cart': False,
    
}
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    cartItems=order.get_cart_items,     
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    context['in_cart'] =order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()    
return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

And here is my **html code** for that button

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if in_cart %}
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"
class="btnabc btnabc-warning update-cart">Added</button>
 {% else %}
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"
class="btnabc btnabc-warning update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
{% endif %}
 {% else %}
<button class="btnabc btnabc-warning"><a href="/login/">Add to
Cart</a></button>
{% endif %}
```

But it does not seem to be working even if product is not in cart it shows Added Please suggest me a way so that on my html code i can check whether the item exists in the cart or not and show the buttons accordingly.
Any help would be appriciated
.

Comment: your are in singleproduct view or cart view ?

Comment: Singleproduct view

Comment: In singleproduct page I want to check if the item is already in Cart or not . If it is already in cart I want to display a added button instead of add to cart button

Comment: ok but cart is not define , you only "types" and  "prods" in context

Comment: Ok . Should I add cartItems in context and if yes then what code will come in html(jinja) to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    cartItems=order.get_cart_items
    types = Category.objects.all()
    prods= Product.objects.filter(productid = id)

    # filter the oder by the product_id , and return True if exsits
    in_cart = order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()

else:
    types = Category.objects.all()
    prods= Product.objects.filter(productid = id)
    cartItems=[]

    # default False
    in_cart = False

# no forget to add in context
return render(request,"singleproduct.html", {'types':types,'prods':prods, 'in_cart': in_cart})
```

in html:

```
    {% if in_cart %}
        already in cart
    {% else %}
        Add in cart
    {% endif %}
```

**edit:**
you can optimize your view like this, dot exactly same

```
def singleproduct(request, id):
    context = {
        'types': Category.objects.all(),
        'prods': Product.objects.filter(productid = id),
        'in_cart': False,
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        order = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=request.user.customer, complete=False)[0]
        context['in_cart'] = order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()
    return render(request,"singleproduct.html", context)
```

Comment: I copied your singleproduct view and changed html(see in above question)

Comment: Even if the product is not in cart it is showing added button instead of add to cart

Comment: you have the same result  in condition, look your html

Comment: Yeah sorry but I changed that. But still if i login and click on add to cart . The product is added to cart but the bbutton does not change to added

Comment: Yep..The page reloads but it doesnt change the add to cart to added. I have changed the html in the question

Comment: you have add in_cart in context ? and how are you sure is add in cart , do you see that in console or admin panel ?

Comment: I have added your views for singleproduct exactly the same. I  see that the product in cart page itself that the products are added to cart

Comment: edit your first post and add your actual view, and all of Order, OrderItem, Product models , thanks

Comment: ok , what is your field productid  in Product model ?

Comment: AttributeError at /category/singleproduct/D0001
'Order' object has no attribute 'products'      Now I am getting this error :  context['in_cart'] = order.products.filter(product_id=id).exists(). when i open single product page

Comment: ok try this  ,    order.orderitems.filter(product__productid=id).exists()
or   order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()

Comment: 'Order' object has no attribute 'orderitems'  now this error

Comment: try the seconde , order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()

Comment: Done Now it seems to work....Also I want to know shouldnt there be a created infront of order like order , created= Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=request.user.customer, complete=False)[0]  and also what is this [0] for ? Is it for getting the first product

Comment: the methods get_or_create return a list of 2 value, first the object , the second a Boolean ,   if model as create , the seconde value set to True , else False , the first is alway the obj, so when you do  get_or_create(...)[0], you get only object , you don't care if it was created. .

Comment: I am extremely grateful to you for helping me . I am a beginner in django. Also I am having this problem in the category page where multiple products of multiple categories is displayed.I tried working it out same way as in singleproduct but it is not working in category page. My view for it is in the question.Please check it out once

Comment: create new question to see that ;)

Comment: Please consider helping:)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215410/i-want-to-check-whether-the-products-in-the-category-page-exists-in-cart-then-sh