# I want to check whether the products in the category page exists in cart then show a added icon in webpage using django and jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a category page(having multiple products which have add to card button under them) in which I have a add to cart button but if that product already exists in the cart I want to show a Added to cart icon instead.I am not able to figure out the way to check that. Here is my models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=False)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    productid=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And here is my **views.py**

```
def category(request):
context = {
    'types' : Category.objects.all(),
    'prods': Product.objects.filter(),
    'cartItems':[],
    'in_cart': False,
    
}
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    cartItems=order.get_cart_items,     
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    context['in_cart'] =order.orderitem_set.filter(product__productid=id).exists()    
return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

And here is my html code for that button

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if in_cart %}
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"
class="btnabc btnabc-warning update-cart">Added</button>
 {% else %}
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add"
class="btnabc btnabc-warning update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
{% endif %}
 {% else %}
<button class="btnabc btnabc-warning"><a href="/login/">Add to
Cart</a></button>
{% endif %}
```

But it does not seem to be working even if product is not in cart it shows Added Please suggest me a way so that on my html code i can check whether the item exists in the cart or not and show the buttons accordingly. Any help would be appriciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context['list_cart'] = order.orderitem_set.values_list('product__id', flat=True)
```

the values_list return a list with only field selected ( here is `product__id`)

result look like that `[55, 88, 99, 123, 42 ...ect]`

so in template you can search if product.id is in list

html:

```
{% if product.id in list_cart %}
    this id already in cart
{% else %}
    add to cart
{% endif %}
```